# How can I pass in 2 parameters to a AsyncTask class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm loading a bitmap in the background using the AsyncTask class.  I use the the execute method to take in a array of strings for the URL of the bitmap to load.  I would like to load the bitmap into different Imagevues.  My idea was to pass in a URL and a reference to a image vue.

I can't figure out a easy way to do this, because execute only takes in 1 parameter. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper object to hold the two parameters, or just use something like an ArrayList or Dictionary and stick both your parameters in it.

Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: I was thinking about the wrappeer class, but seemed messy.  I did not think about the arraulist -Ted