# pass parameter to AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am build android app which is supposed to open barcode scanner screen and scan the barcode, then send the barcode string to a webservice. I have done barcode reading part, sending static strings to webservice. I am sending strings to webservice asynchronously.

here is my code

```
public class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            execute__barcode_webservice();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}
```

I need to pass two string to "execute__barcode_webservice()"

This is how I call asynctask to send strings.

```
 AsyncCallWS soap_object = x.new AsyncCallWS();
 soap_object.execute();
```

How do I pass two strings to soap_object and then to execute__barcode_webservice()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
soap_object.execute(new String []{"StringOne","StringTwo"});
```

You can also do :

```
soap_object.execute("StringOne","StringTwo");
```

In `doInBackground`, params is a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) argument, so just do :

```
execute__barcode_webservice(params[0], params[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
AsyncCallWS soap_object = x.new AsyncCallWS();

soap_object.execute(new String []{"String_one","String_two"});
```

Then in **doInBackground**

```
 execute__barcode_webservice(params[0],params[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in an array of strings so:

```
new String[] info = ...
soap_object.execute(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Parameterobjects, see this thread, answer of David Wasser: [How can you pass multiple primitive parameters to AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069669/how-can-you-pass-multiple-primitive-parameters-to-asynctask)