# How to send values to another method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have these strings latRepr and LngRepr and I want to send them to the getDirecoes method. The GetDirecoes class is a AsyncTask.

This is how I start the method:

> new GetDirecoes().execute();

So, how do I send those strings to here:

```
private class GetDirecoes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements Serializable {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {}
```

Comment: Send these values as parameter in execute() method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you pass multiple primitive parameters to AsyncTask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069669/how-can-you-pass-multiple-primitive-parameters-to-asynctask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new GetDirecoes().execute(latRepr,LngRepr);
```

this is how you can pass.

```
private class GetDirecoes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> implements Serializable {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
  String latRepr=params[0];
  String LngRepr=params[1];
 }
 }
```

Comment: How you can pass String with parameter type Void.

Comment: Apologies.Made mistake. and i corrected. thanks for your valuable comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
new GetDirecoes().execute(latRepr,LngRepr);
```

and after that

```
private class GetDirecoes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> implements Serializable {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      String latRepr = params[0];
      String LngRepr= params[1];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor in AsyncTask

```
private class GetDirecoes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements Serializable {

    String mLat;
    String mLng;
    public GetDirecoes(String lat, String lng){
        mLat = lat;
        mLng = lng;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
}
```

and pass the value

```
new GetDirecoes(latRepr,LngRepr).execute();
```

Comment: @downvoter Would you care to point out the reason for downvote?

Comment: Was not me, but why using a custom constructor when the class itself provides better access to simple structured data?

Comment: Ofcourse that is another solution. And yeah for that he has to pass the values inside execute() method.

Answer (score 0):

your first `Void` represent the type of params in `doInBackground` method.

So you can construct your `AsyncTask` as this :

```
private class GetDirecoes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> implements Serializable {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String lat = params[0];
        String lng = params[1];
        ...
    }
```

and then call your AsyncTask like this :

```
new GetDirecoes().execute(latRepr, lngRepr);
```

You will find more info there : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Your GetDirecoes is a class, not a method.

What you can do is create a constructor that takes in two String parameters, and store the variables as fields of that GetDircoes.

```
private class GetDirecoes {
    private String latRepr;
    private String LngRepr;
    public GetDirecoes(String latRepr, String LngRepr) {
          this.latRepr = latRepr;
          this.LngRepr = LngRepr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {}
}
```

Then you should be able to call `new GetDirecoes(latRepr,LngRepr).execute();`

Answer (score 0):

The `AsyncTask` has generic types which in your case are `Void, Void, Void`. These 3 types are parameters for the methods

```
doInBackground(params...)
onProgressUpdate(params...)
```

and

```
onPostExecute(Result)
```

So if your first type would be String (`AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>`), your `doInBackground` method would look like

```
doInBackground(String... params) {
  String firstparam = params[0];
}
```

Please consider to check if params is not null and it's size greater than 0

It's all documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)