# Asynchronous App for multiplication can not be compiled

Tags: java, android

i try to make my 1st `AsyncTask` in App. This application should download from 2 field numbers, then multiplication and display score in 3rd field.
It is easy, but i want to learn how to use AsyncTask and i want this metod(for multiplication) put in other thread.
In my opinion it look fine, but AndroidStudio underline my class `MyTask`. And suggets impement that same method... :

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Double... params) {
    return null;
}
```

Can i ask for tips, how i should do now ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private EditText editText,editText2,editText3;
    private String a,b,c;
    private Double x1,x2,x3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                a = editText.getText().toString();
                b = editText2.getText().toString();
                x1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
                x2 = Double.parseDouble(b);

                calc();

            }

        });

    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Double x1, Double x2) {

            x3 = x1 * x2;
            c = String.valueOf(x3);
            editText3.setText(c);

            return null;
        }

    }

    private void calc() {
        new MyTask().execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: If it underlines, it tells you what the error is.  Hover the mouse cursor to find out.

Comment: i added more information, you can check

Comment: You must run in on uiThread to update the view from doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

So you need replace
protected Void doInBackground(Double x1, Double x2)
in your code with
protected Void doInBackground(Double... params)
and you can access parameters like params[0] params[1] etc

See examples e.g. here
[How can you pass multiple primitive parameters to AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069669/how-can-you-pass-multiple-primitive-parameters-to-asynctask)